# Sqlite relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: android, sqlite

Sobre relacionamento entre tabelas:

Tentei rodar o seguinte código e o SQLite me retorna o seguinte erro:

> table "Jogos" has more than one primary key

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `times`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (
  `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `sigla` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `imagem` MEDIUMTEXT NUL);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Jogos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jogos` (
  `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `rodada` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_hora` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `local` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `gols_mandante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `gols_visitante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_mandante` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_visitante` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`, `id_mandante`, `id_visitante`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Jogos_times1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_mandante`)
    REFERENCES `times` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Jogos_times2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_visitante`)
    REFERENCES `times` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Jogos_times1_idx` on `Jogos` (`id_mandante` ASC);
CREATE INDEX `fk_Jogos_times2_idx` on `Jogos` (`id_visitante` ASC);
```

Parece que o erro surge quando tento adicionar as chaves estrangeiras oriundas da tabela `times` na tabela `jogos`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que estás a definir duas `PRIMARY KEY` na sua tabela.

E só pode ter **UMA** `PRIMARY KEY` por tabela.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Jogos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jogos` (
  `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,       -- UMA
  `rodada` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_hora` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `local` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `gols_mandante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `gols_visitante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_mandante` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_visitante` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`, `id_mandante`, `id_visitante`),     -- DUAS
```

Apague a `PRIMARY KEY` do `_id` e vai funcionar:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Jogos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jogos` (
  `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,      
  `rodada` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_hora` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `local` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `gols_mandante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `gols_visitante` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_mandante` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_visitante` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`, `id_mandante`, `id_visitante`),
```

Comment: Obrigado Jorge, mas não posso apagar a pk _id pois essa é a chave primária da tabela jogos. Não seria apagar "id_mandante" e "id_visitante" ficando assim: PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)

Comment: E se esse for o caso, não perderia a integridade relacional?

Comment: Não, manténs a integridade relacional. As tabelas não precisam de ter primary key o id, pode ser outro campo ou um chave primária múltipla como tu tens